# Issue with piping stringr str_detect into str_extract - extract is only pulling text from 1st row: argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to create a new column which just contains certain numeric data from an expression.

Here's my data: https://pastebin.com/hYg3zqYz

I just need the numbers that come after Bipolar in column 12.

Here's what works

```
p <- df %>% 
      select(where(~ any(stringr::str_detect(.x, "Bipolar")))) #returns correct column
```

Where I try then try to make a new column that pulls just the text, it only ever returns the first row, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
p %>%
      mutate(group = "sr_bipol",
             sr_bipol = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(., "[0-9].[0-9]+"))) %>% 
       select(group, sr_bipol)

# A tibble: 20 × 2
   group    sr_bipol
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 sr_bipol     7.83
 2 sr_bipol     7.83
 3 sr_bipol     7.83
 4 sr_bipol     7.83
 5 sr_bipol     7.83
.....................
```

I also get the error code:

```
 argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

After loading in a new case, I tried to use the following solutio but ran into a new error

new data: https://paste.kodi.tv/azuramoguh

```
df %>% 
  transmute(across(where(~ any(stringr::str_detect(.x, "Bipolar"))), 
   ~ as.numeric(str_extract(.x, "(?<=Bipolar\\s)[0-9]\\.[0-9]+")), 
     .names = "sr_bipol{str_remove(.col, '[.]+')}"))

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "call_text", value = c("df %>% ...",  : 
  replacement has 13 rows, data has 12
```

Also tried:

```
df %>% 
  select(where(~ any(stringr::str_detect(.x, "Bipolar")))) %>% #this finds the column with the bipolar ##voltage data
  transmute(group = "sr_bipol",
            sr_bipol = as.numeric(
              stringr::str_extract(pull(.,1), "[0-9].[0-9]+") #str_extract expects a vector, so "pull" to #change from df to vector
              )
            ) %>%
  bind_cols(carto_lv_sr_volt %>% select(x:z))

Error in `select()`:
! `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
```

Comment: Is the `p` in the second code block subset of 'df'

Comment: @akrun not a subset, it's the same exact p as is listed in the code above. I just wanted to illustrate which parts of the code work and which dont.

Comment: ok, got it.  I used `transmute` to return only that columns instead of first selecting.  If there are more than one column in 'p', yu can loop `across` as in my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` refers to the whole dataset (`str_extract` needs a vector as input and not a data.frame). According to `?str_extract`

> string - Input vector. Either a character vector, or something coercible to one.

We may need to apply `str_extract` on the column 12.  As the column name for 12 prefix include `...` that are unusual column names, use backticks to access the column values

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  transmute(group = 'sr_bipol', 
    sr_bipol = as.numeric(str_extract(`...12`, "(?<=Bipolar\\s)[0-9]\\.[0-9]+")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   group    sr_bipol
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 sr_bipol     7.83
 2 sr_bipol     2.34
 3 sr_bipol     1.97
 4 sr_bipol     1.94
 5 sr_bipol     2.85
 6 sr_bipol     2.92
 7 sr_bipol     3.05
 8 sr_bipol     2.80
 9 sr_bipol     3.43
10 sr_bipol     2.11
11 sr_bipol     2.80
12 sr_bipol     1.81
13 sr_bipol     1.84
14 sr_bipol     3.87
15 sr_bipol     1.68
16 sr_bipol     2.21
17 sr_bipol     2.97
18 sr_bipol     3.09
19 sr_bipol     2.84
20 sr_bipol     3.48
```

---

The `p` data is a single column `tibble/data.frame`.  When we use `.`, it selects the data.frame as such i.e.

```
> str(p)
tibble [20 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ...12: chr [1:20] "Bipolar 7.827 / Unipolar 16.911 / LAT -9.0" "Bipolar 2.34 / Unipolar 9.09 / LAT -10.0" "Bipolar 1.974 / Unipolar 9.219 / LAT -11.0" "Bipolar 1.938 / Unipolar 10.572 / LAT -9.0" ...
> str_extract(p, "[0-9].[0-9]+")
[1] "7.827"
Warning message:
In stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

It extracts the value from the first instance and this got recycled to create the whole column of 7.8

---

If there are more than one column having the 'Bipolar' we may loop `across` (modify the `transmute` to `mutate` if we want to keep all other columns from the original data)

```
df %>% 
  transmute(across(where(~ any(stringr::str_detect(.x, "Bipolar"), na.rm = TRUE)), 
   ~ as.numeric(str_extract(.x, "(?<=Bipolar\\s)[0-9]\\.[0-9]+")), 
     .names = "sr_bipol{str_remove(.col, '[.]+')}"))
# A tibble: 20 × 1
   sr_bipol12
        <dbl>
 1       7.83
 2       2.34
 3       1.97
 4       1.94
 5       2.85
 6       2.92
 7       3.05
 8       2.80
 9       3.43
10       2.11
11       2.80
12       1.81
13       1.84
14       3.87
15       1.68
16       2.21
17       2.97
18       3.09
19       2.84
20       3.48
```

Comment: I tried to run a new case through this code using your method and a variation but now it's not running. Updated in the original post with issue :(

Comment: @myfatson your column had some NAs,  which returns NA with `any`.  YOu can use `na.rm = TRUE` as in my update (now it works with the new dput)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  select(...12) %>% 
  separate(...12, into="group", sep = "\\/") %>%
  mutate(sr_bipol = parse_number(group),
         group= str_extract(group, '[A-Za-z]+'))

   group   sr_bipol
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Bipolar     7.83
 2 Bipolar     2.34
 3 Bipolar     1.97
 4 Bipolar     1.94
 5 Bipolar     2.85
 6 Bipolar     2.92
 7 Bipolar     3.05
 8 Bipolar     2.80
 9 Bipolar     3.43
10 Bipolar     2.11
11 Bipolar     2.80
12 Bipolar     1.81
13 Bipolar     1.84
14 Bipolar     3.87
15 Bipolar     1.68
16 Bipolar     2.21
17 Bipolar     2.97
18 Bipolar     3.09
19 Bipolar     2.84
20 Bipolar     3.48
```